# How do I control these bumper cars?

Tags: team-fortress-2

It's so confusing, I'm trying to turn and it does it really horribly, someone said you can fly in bumper cars, I can't figure out how.

Also once I turn into a ghost how do I respawn? It seems I can't respawn and there's no timer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Controls**

The default bumper car controls are W and S for forward and back, with A and D for turning. Space bar will make you jump slightly. Note that the bumper cars turn fairly slowly.

If the charge meter below your damage percent is full, your secondary attack (right click by default) will make you boost for a short time.  That is, go really fast.

Ramming other players will make their damage percentage go up.  As their damage percentage gets higher, they're more likely to be knocked off the map, turning them into a ghost.  Bomb Head does the most damage, followed by Punch, Boosting, followed by a normal bump.

The action button, normally H (and possibly primary attack/left click) will activate your current spell.  Note that spells only appear on the Duck Hunt and Soccer Match games.

**Spells**

The available spells in Bumper Cars are:

- Invincibility - Makes you invincible for a short time.  This prevents enemies from knocking you around.
- Parachute - Makes you jump in the air then glide slowly down.  This is likely what you had heard about for flying.  However, it isn't really useful for the two bumper car modes that have spells.
- Bomb Head - Turns your head into a bomb.  Ramming an enemy player will force them into the air and likely off the edge, although a well-timed boost can save them.
- Punch - Sends a giant boxing glove straight ahead of you.  Knocks players away.  Only seems to appear on Soccer Match.

**Respawning**

You don't respawn as normal in the bumper car mode.  Instead, touching one of your team's living players will bring you back to life where they're located.  This makes the Falling Platforms mode more difficult as you only win if everyone on the other team is dead at once.

Comment: I think your list of spells is incomplete.

Comment: @ColinD For bumper cars?  Which one(s) am I missing?  Those are the only 3 I remember seeing during bumper cars.

Comment: I remember a spell that pushes everyone who is around you away. I cant find any other spells lists online to confirm :/. Best I can do is: https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/October_29,_2014_Patch has `tf/tf2_misc_dir.vpk/models/props_halloween/hwn_spell_boxing_glove.dx80.vtx`

Comment: @ColinD Huh, I must never have gotten that one, unless it's combined with the invincibility one (which I doubt).